# VMware Horizon Client

Tags: 19.04

I have read the responses to difficulty in installing VMware Horizon Client on older versions of Ubuntu. But nothing recently. I use Linux for everything, but have to resort to Windows (unfortunately) when it comes to VMware Horizon Client for Ubuntu 19. Any suggestions on how to install? BTW, I am not a newb. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Personally I have not had any problems with the Horizont client since Ubuntu 16.04 to 19.04.
I have installed and updated it following the product documentation.

What error does it show when you run VMware-Horizon-Client-5.0.0-12557422.x64.bundle?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for Ubuntu 19.10 and VMware Horizon 5.4.1:

Step 1:

```
file VMware-Horizon-Client-5.4.1-15988340.x64.bundle
```

Step 2:

```
chmod +x VMware-Horizon-Client-5.4.1-15988340.x64.bundle
```

Step 3:

```
sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-5.4.1-15988340.x64.bundle
```

If you get `gtk` error, run the following command between steps 2 and 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2
```